# Google's CSS styling

Tags: naming-conventions

Having been inspecting a few elements on Google, i noticed that their naming conventions are fairly funky, ie.

```
.n-Wa-q-Dc, .n-xb .n-Wa-q-Dc:hover
```

This is clearly not readable/manageable by a human. Is it the opinion that Google's CSS and class names are largely auto generated by server side technology.

I cant see people maintaining such a CSS file myself.

Would it be advisable for such a large system (Google) to have *any* people managing the CSS and just to let the systems handle it?

Answer (score 0):

They should have a version that is human-readable (for development) and, from that, generate the obfuscated version (for deployment).  Most likely, a search-n-replace is performed on the names of the scripts or stylesheets (from using human-readable to obfuscated ones) before deployment.

Comment: nice, never thought about that!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though they probably ran their css through a minifier to reduce the size of the css file.  As